# Why does the C++ standard not change std::set to use std::less<> as its default template argument?

Tags: c++, c++14, standards, c++20, backwards-compatibility

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::literals;

int main()
{
    auto v1 = std::set<std::string, std::less<>>{"abc"s};
    v1.contains("abc"s);  // ok
    v1.contains("abc"sv); // ok
    
    auto v2 = std::set{"abc"s};
    v2.contains("abc"s);  // ok
    v2.contains("abc"sv); // error
}
```

`v1.contains("abc"sv);` is more efficient than `v1.contains("abc"s);`, because it needn't to construct a string object.

However, the C++ standard uses `std::less<T>`, rather than `std::less<>`, as `std::set`'s default template argument. So, *CTAD (Class Template Argument Deduction)* doesn't work on `std::less<>`, I have to write ugly `std::set<std::string, std::less<>>{"abc"s}`, rather than `std::set{"abc"s}`.

Why does the C++ standard not change `std::set` to use `std::less<>` as its default template argument? Just for backward compatibility?

Comment: Maybe the original(?) [N3465](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3465.pdf) will shed some light.

Comment: Err, because it would violate [tag:backwards-compatibility]? If you don't think this is a big deal, remember that American Express sued the Cobol-85 committee for violating it.

Comment: `using std::literals;` should be `using namespace std::literals;`

Comment: `typedef std::set<std::string, std::less<>> svset;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is because they thought it wasn't so great improvement to break backward compatibility.

Another reason is because `std::set` with `std::less<Key>` existed even before C++11 (starting from C++03 I guess) and `std::less<>` appeared only in C++14. So if they move to `std::set` with `std::less<>` then you have to force C++14 when using set, or you have to make two kinds of sets - one for C++03 and one for C++14.

Also if you start from C++14 making set being std::less<>-based then your pre-C++14 code will start to behave differently sometimes. For example your code relied on calling Key's constructor for some reason when adding to set, then suddenly if you add option `-std=c++14` your old code starts doing other things.

Usually STD people make such changes that switching from C++11 to C++14 doesn't break code's behaviour. Only downswitching from C++14 to C++11 can break something(usually non-compiling). In other words it is backward compatibility breaking change to use std::less<>. Such changes are usually only done by introducing new class name for such specializations.

Comment: FWIW, the Standard Template Library (STL, which is **not** "STandard Library") was part of C++98.

Answer (score 5):

Moving from `std::set<T, std::less<T>>` to `std::set<T, std::less<>>` can make key-finding algorithms more efficient, if the search-key never has to be converted.

Conversely, it can make them less efficient if the conversion occurrs on every call to the comparator, instead of once in the caller on starting the algorithm. Those conversions can be quite expensive.

Especially if the conversion from search-key to `T` is lossy, there isn't even a guarantee both would yield the same result!

For these reasons, such a change is not a straight upgrade, but a breaking change. And the committee is quite loath to introduce those.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does the C++ standard not change `std::set` to use `std::less<>` as its default template argument? Just for backward compatibility?

This would be an ABI break.

```cpp
// a.cpp
void f(std::set<int> const&) { ... }

// b.cpp
void g() {
    std::set<int> s = /* ... */;
    f(s);
}
```

If `a.cpp` is compiled on C++11, `f` takes a `std::set<int, std::less<int>>`.

If the standard library changed the default comparison from `std::less<T>` to `std::less<void>` in C++14 ([N3421](https://wg21.link/n3421) was only written in 2012), and `b.cpp` was compiled on C++14, then `s` would be a `std::set<int, std::less<void>>`. And now we fail to link.

Comment: Mixing settings can easily break ODR anyway. C++11 `std::set` doesn't have same tokens that C++14 `std::set`.